# CSS gets distorted on click of a certain control

Tags: html, css, asp.net, checkboxlist

Hi I am using the following CSS script to align the checkboxes in my ASP.NET Project-

```
.checkbox-grid td 
        {
             text-align: left !important;
             display: inline-table !important;
             float: left !important;
             width: 183px !important;
        }
```

[The Image of the page before Distortion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5nz6.png)

There is a control on the page called open record that opens the selected record on to a new tab. Whenever I select a record and open it the rendering of checkboxs in the current page gets distorted as shown in the Image below

[The image of the page after distortion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPR9Y.png)

I have set the max-width of the table and the row to 800px yet it breaks.

Any clue where am i going wrong?

Here are the lines used by me..

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>The controls on the left side</td>
        <td>
            <div style="margin:15px 15px !important;">
                <asp:CheckBoxList runat="server" ID="valArea" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatColumns = "4" CssClass="checkbox-grid">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Anupam Nagar">Anupam Nagar</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Atulbaug">Atulbaug</asp:ListItem>
                    . . . and so on 
                </asp:CheckBoxList>
            </div>

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Post some of your html, that would be helpful.

Comment: <table>
     <tr>
          <td>The controls on the left side</td>
          <td>
          <div style="margin:15px 15px !important;">
                            <asp:CheckBoxList runat="server" ID="valArea" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" CssClass="checkbox-grid" Width="800px">
                                <asp:ListItem Value="Anupam Nagar">Anupam Nagar</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="Atulbaug">Atulbaug</asp:ListItem>
.
.
. and so on
          </td>
     </tr>
</table>

Comment: Can you edit your answer with this info, it would make it more readable.

Comment: Done, I have added those lines in the question itself.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You're setting `RepeatDirection="Horizontal"` which tells it to lay out your controls that way. 
You can also set `RepeatColumns = "4"` to specify the number of columns.

Comment: This almost worked. Yet the checkbox list gets distorted on click of Open Record control.
This is how it looks after I click the 'Open Record' Control 
 http://i.stack.imgur.com/fcA1N.png